# Exports in compile command

Tags: shell, compilation, environment

I'm using the Anaconda distribution for Numpy, Ipython etc. and during the installation the following was added to my .bashrc:

```
# added by Anaconda2 2.4.0 installer
export PATH="/home/matthias/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

when I run M-x shell in emacs "ipython bla.py" works perfectly fine. However, when I run M-x compile and then enter "ipython bla.py" it will say:

```
ipython bla.py
/bin/bash: ipython: Kommando nicht gefunden.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 127 at Tue Dec  8 13:35:59
```

How do I tell emacs about my anaconda installation, like I did in .bashrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move `$PATH` to `~/.profile`.  `.bashrc` is only for interactive sessions; variables in this file do *not* propagate to GUI applications.

Once you moved the setting, restart your system, and Emacs should see your new `$PATH`.